# Marketing Cloud Issue with Sender profile using reply mail management

Tags: marketing-cloud

We understand the email address for the RMM domain is not real but would have thought it would forward messages sent to that email address to the specified email address in the forward section. Issue is recipients copy and pasted the fake email address into their contacts and try emailing it directly. They not receive a bounceback but the email doesn't go anywhere either. Anyone find a way to resolve this? See screenshot of the sender profile used to send:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue raised before, but all roads led to the email entering a black hole. The official response I received from support was:

> "This is not a valid inbox so if a subscriber were to create a new
>   email and send it to [Sender Domain] it would not work. Since we do
>   not create a valid email for this process there is no option
>   set/modify this process."

I can't imagine this being a terribly common occurrence, but if it does become a problem you can always make a note if your emails or use a 'noreply@' email address.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately noreply@ reduces deliverability and this client of our wants to encourage people to reply. It works fine if the recipient replies directly to the email it gets forwarded appropriately but she is getting a bunch of people that saved the from email address into their contacts and wondering why they are unable to email it so its definitely a problem. Wish there was just some way to forward those emails to a real email address. Seems like standard domain manangment functionality